# Entity Framework: Avoid multiple saves for circular references

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm getting this exception when calling SaveChanges on my EF ObjectContext:

```
Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints
```

I think the problem is because I have a circular dependency on my DB model.

i.e.

Table Users

- Id
- ProfilePictureId

Table Pictures

- Id
- UserId

I'm creating a new user and setting the picture

```
var user = _db.Users.CreateObject();
var picture = _db.Pictures.CreateObject();

picture.User = user;
user.ProfilePicture = picture;

_db.SaveChanges();
```

But that throws the exception.

If I add an extra call to SaveChanges() after I set the picture's User It works just fine, I just want to avoid that double trip to the DB.

Any ideas of how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to avoid calling `SaveChanges` twice with your database design. You can't insert user with dependency to picture which is not inserted yet (FK will throw exception) and in the same time you can't insert picture with dependency to user which is not inserted yet (again FK will throw exception). That is not feature of EF that is feature of DB itself.

You also don't need to avoid multiple `SaveChanges` calls because of multiple roundtrips. EF doesn't have command batching so each insert, update or delete has its own roundtrip to database anyway.

If you want to call single SaveChanges you must change your database as follows:

Table Users

- Id (PK, IDENTITY)

Table Pictures

- Id (PK, FK to Users.Id, No IDENTITY)

This is native one-to-one relation where User is principal and Picture is dependent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought the whole idea of having one SaveChanges() call was to execute all operations at once in the server. Regarding the change in the model, the relationship I need is one to many (a user can upload multiple pictures), but at the same time one of those images will be the profile picture. I'll stick with the two calls to SaveChanges then.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it's enough to make the assignment once (either setting user or picture) ie:

```
var user = _db.Users.CreateObject();
var picture = _db.Pictures.CreateObject();

user.ProfilePicture = picture;

_db.SaveChanges();
```

You are creating new entities at first two lines, and you 'link' them by `user.ProfilePicture = picture`. EF should handle the rest.
You don't need to setup relation from both sides.

Edit: What about this?

```
var user = _db.Users.CreateObject();
var picture = _db.Pictures.CreateObject();

picture.user = user;
user.ProfilePictureId = picture.Id;


_db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: The problem is that there are two different relationships, all pictures  will have a UserId (whoever owns the picture), but only some of them will be profilePictures. That's why there's a UserId field in the Pictures table and that's why the double assignment is necessary.

Comment: Ah, I was solving something similar. You have to use onModelCreating method. Give me a moment to find that.

Comment: Actually no... I got different scenario and I was doing it code first. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, got another idea. You might want to set just that int value, not whole entity. This way you are not doing double assignment, but the correct FK should be saved in db. I have edited my answer

Comment: The problem there is that picture.Id is an autoincremental field, therefore it won't be set until the SaveChanges() method is called. I found another thread where they say it's not supported. Bummer. Thanks anyway!