# Working with codependent entities in EF C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, dependency-management

I have to Entities `A` and `B`.

`A` has fields:
`id` (PK) and `b_fk` (FK to `B's id`).
`B` has similar fields:
`id` (PK) and `a_fk` (FK to `A's id`).

Now I want to create object `A` and `B`:

```
createAAndBMethod(Entities context){
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    a.b_fk = b;
    b.a_fk = a;
    context.As.AddObject(a);
    context.Bs.AddObject(b);
}

someImportantMethod(){
    //do sth
    Entities context = new Entities(...);
    //do sth, maybe some changes to db on context
    createAAndBMethod(context);
    //do sth, maybe some changes to db on context
    context.SaveChanges();// <-- here I'm getting error
}
```

Saving doesn't work with error: `Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.`

Is there any way to get this working with one save?
I need to create both objects in some code which shouldn't be saving changes, so I can't execute `context.SaveChanges()` anywhere before.

On `context.SaveChanges()` could happen something like:

```
 Create newA with nulled field b_fk
 Create newB with a_fk = newA
 Set newA.b_fk to newB
```

Update:
both `a_fk` and `b_fk` are nullable. I'm working with MS SQL and Azure SQL.

Update2:
I changed `createAAndBMethod(Entities context)`to:

```
createAAndBMethod(Entities context){
    A a = new A();
    context.As.AddObject(a);
    B b = new B();
    a.b_fk = b;
}
```

But it still doesn't work with same error.

Comment: next time, you have to include the version of entity of framework :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you model has a problem; A table has a foreign key reference to B table; and B table has a foreign key reference to A table. Then why don't you merge these tables and only create a single table?

If you are trying to create a one to one relationship, this is not the proper way.

UPDATE:
DB design is not proper. Only creating a foreign key in Table B is enough. there is no need to create a foreign key in Table A as such a design satisfies "A may have 0 or many Bs".

Comment: No, there could be many `Bs` pointing to one `A`, for example:
`A`: `a`, `B`: `b1`, `b2`, `b3`. `a.b_fk = b1`, `{allbs}.a_fk = a`. For example `A` is a person, `B` is a tie, `b_fk` is worn tie and `a_fk` is owner.

Comment: @Ari then you example is not proper; you should use a.Bs.Add(b1) etc.

Comment: It still doesn't work, even if I won't set `B.a_fk` field in any way (directly by `a_fk` field or by `Bs` in `A`).

Comment: you problem seems to be related with the model; are using code first?

Comment: There are simple tables like this entites. Both has two fields (and some properties not important for now): id (PK) and FK.

Comment: I feel the type of relation between A and B table is important.

Comment: both have nullable foreign key contsratis to each other

Comment: then you db design is not proper. What is the purpose of having two tables referencing each other? why "A may have 0 or more Bs" is not enough for you?

Comment: Answer was in the last comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove these lines:

```
b.a_fk = a;

context.Bs.AddObject(b);
```

I think you add object `b` to the context twice. EF do this automatically when you add object `a` with a foreign key.

**Update:**

try these 2 variants:

```
  createAAndBMethod1(Entities context)
  {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        a.b_fk = b;
        b.a_fk = a;
        context.As.AddObject(a);
  } 

createAAndBMethod2(Entities context)
{
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        a.b_fk = b;
        context.As.AddObject(a);
        context.SaveChanges();
        b.a_fk = a;
        context.SaveChanges();    
}
```

Comment: I am not sure but for your dependency maybe you need to remove just the second line: context.Bs.AddObject(b);

Comment: Both doesn't work (tried them). It doesn't work even if I remove line `b.a_fk = a`, which is a part of both of them.

Comment: I think this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761495/entity-framework-avoid-multiple-saves-for-circular-references

Comment: I hope your classes A and B have similar structure: public class A 
{public **virtual** B b { get; set; } ...}

Answer (score 0):

Something like you want to use the one context and at the same time you have a two table.

```
    var p = new Person()
    {
        LastName = "test1111111111",
    };
    var c = new Child()
    {
        Name = "Testchild"
    };
    PersonTest(p, c);
```

---

```
    public void PersonTest(Person ob, Child ob2)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var con = new Entities())
            {
                con.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
                var o = new Person();
                if (ob.PersonId > 0)
                    o = con.People.Find(ob.PersonId);

                o.PersonId = ob.PersonId;
                o.LastName = ob.LastName;
                if (ob.PersonId == 0)
                    con.People.Add(o);
                con.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
                con.SaveChanges();
                i = o.PersonId;

                var o2 = new Child();
                if (ob2.ChildrenId > 0)
                    o2 = con.Children.Find(ob.PersonId);

                o2.PersonId = ob2.ChildrenId;
                o2.Name = ob2.Name;
                o2.PersonId = i;
                if (ob2.ChildrenId == 0)
                    con.Children.Add(o2);
                con.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```